# .htaccess and .htpasswd ignore subfolders

Tags: php, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I want to ignore folders on my website, but as I often create subfolders on it, I want to ignore subfolders too.

Here's my .htaccess :

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Auth Required"
AuthUserFile ".htpasswd location"
Require valid-user
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(folder I want to ignore for everyone)$" allow
Order allow,deny
Allow from env=allow
# allow open access to entire site for those IPs:
allow from xx.xx.xxx.xx.xxx
Satisfy any
```

When I go to a subfolder, it keep asking for a login and password, but when I click on "Cancel" to cancel that login, everything goes fine and no other box is shown.
All I want is to not have this box shown.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.htaccess settings **ALWAYS** affects subfolders unless you override it with another .htaccess which would change the behaviour set in parent folder's .htaccess

Comment: Erf, yes. My bad. One of the subfolder I wanted to access had a "deny from all" in his .htaccess....

Comment: Glad it helped. If you plan to stay here for longer, please take a look here too: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235